# como fazer total em lista elementos Python django

Tags: python, django, lista, model, soma

bande dados primário(dado brutos) onde tem valores `.flot` e já estou calculando o total na função `totalv2` está funcionado

```
class Funcionario(models.Model):
    CustoColeta = models.DecimalField( 
     max_digits=8, 
     decimal_places=2, 
     null=False,
     blank=False 
    )

CustoIda = models.DecimalField( 
 max_digits=8, 
 decimal_places=2, 
 null=False, 
 blank=False
)

CustoVenda = models.DecimalField( 
 max_digits=8, 
 decimal_places=2, 
 null=False, 
 blank=False 
)

objetos = models.Manager()


def totalv2(self):
  return sum([self.CustoColeta,self.CustoIda,self.NfDeEntrada])
```

meu problema se deve ao fato que preciso de uma forma de calcular o total (bruto) ou seja pegar o valor de todos `totalv2` (que é um sub-total) e somar
para ter o valor todos fretes já realizados

```
class conta(models.Model):
def totalfrete(self):
  for x in Funcionario:
    x=sum([self.totalv2])
    return x
```

foi criado uma segunda classe mas não tive sucesso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parece-me que precisas de rever um pouco a tua função, senão vejamos. O x do Funcionário é que recebe o SUM e retorna em cada iteração (???), se queres o bruto tens de somar tudo e retornar no fim do loop. Penso que algo assim.

```
def totalfrete(self):
  result = 0
  for x in Funcionario:
    result += (x.CustoColeta + [self.totalv2])
  return result #retorna o resultado no fim, como tinhas retorna em cada iteração o 'x'
```